# Search box placeholder not chanigng

Tags: magento-1.7, search, catalogsearch, phtml

I am using Magento 1.7. I want to change the placeholder for my search box.

Currently I have

[image]

And I want to change this text to "Qué quieres encontrar?".

To do so, I changed the corresponding code in `form.mini.phtml` under `app/design/frontend/default/CUSTOM_THEME/template/catalogsearch`, to the following:

```
<form id="search_mini_form" action="<?php echo $this->helper('catalogsearch')->getResultUrl() ?>" method="get">
    <div class="form-search">
        <label for="search"><?php echo $this->__('Search:') ?></label>
        <input id="search" type="text" name="<?php echo $this->helper('catalogsearch')->getQueryParamName() ?>" placeholder="Qué quieres encontrar?" value="¿Qué quieres encontrar?" class="input-text" />
        <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Search') ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Qué quieres encontrar?') ?></span></span></button>
        <?php /*<div id="search_autocomplete" class="search-autocomplete"></div>*/?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
            var searchForm = new Varien.searchForm('search_mini_form', 'search', 'Qué quieres encontrar?');
            //searchForm.initAutocomplete('<?php //echo $this->helper('catalogsearch')->getSuggestUrl() ?>', 'search_autocomplete');
        //]]>
        </script>
    </div>
</form>
```

But didn't get success. Right now I can see the new text only after I click on the search box, but not by default. I already cleared Magento's and browser's cache.

Can anyone please tell me how can I change the text? Any help is much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that there was an extension that was the responsible for the text that appeared in my search box.

That's my case, but if you have a similar trouble, try to go to `Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Developer` and then allow template hints in order to see which is the .phtml used in your case.